# Applying reference to a Cell

Tags: reactjs, fixed-data-table

I am using FixedDataTable v0.6.0 within a mostly Angular app.

I have the following column:

```
<Column
  key={colIndex}
  columnKey={countKey}
  width={columnWidths[countKey]}
  flexGrow={1}
  isResizable={true}
  allowCellsRecycing={true}
  header={<Cell className={HEADER_CELL_CLASS}>{count}</Cell>}
  cell={function(cellData) {
    var rowIndex = cellData.rowIndex;
    var row = tableRows[rowIndex];
    var col = row.columns[colIndex];
    var tag = count + "_col" + colIndex + "_row" + rowIndex;

    var interopOn = !_this.props.isDemo && !col.isTotalConversion;
    var className = row.isOverallRow ? OVERALL_CELL_CLASS : "";
    className += interopOn ? " interop-tooltip-content interop-on" : "";

    return <Cell className={className}
                 key={tag}
                 ref={tag}
                 onClick={_this._onCellClick.bind(_this, row.breakoutKey, col.step.queryStepIdx, tag)}
                 onMouseEnter={_this.props.onRowMouseEnter.bind(_this, row.breakoutKey)}
                 onMouseLeave={_this.props.onRowMouseLeave.bind(_this, row.breakoutKey)}
                 width={columnWidths[countKey]}>
                 {col.displayCount}
          </Cell>
  }}
/>
```

Specifically, in the `Cell` tag, I'm attempting to keep a reference to the element so `_onCellClick` I can call `this.refs[refTag]`, grab the element, and place a fixed element near that element (a tooltip).

What I need is either:
(a) a way to get the ref property to work (it looks like it doesn't due to how the Cell is cloned over).
(b) a way to get a reference to either the element or event bound to the `onClick` event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugh, I overlooked one big point about onClicks and events.

I just had to change my onClick call to: `onClick={function(e){_this._onInteropCellClick(row.breakoutKey, col.step.queryStepIdx, e);}}`

Bypass refs altogether.